# netstat with full command name (like in htop)

Tags: netstat

I'm running a few different services via mono, each on there own port, but when I use netstat to check which have assigned a port and which haven't, all I get are 2 processes called "mono", no way to tell which is which, apart from looking at the port, which can sometimes change.

Is it possible to get netstat to show the "command" for each port, like htop does for processes?

This way I can tell what process is which.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has taken a bit of doing, but I've managed to create a filter to append the program's parameter list:

```
netstat -p | while l="$(line)";\
  do p="$(sed -En 's/^.*( [0-9]+)\/[^ ]*.*/\1/gp'<<<"$l")";\
     [ "$p" == "" ] || p=" ## $(ps -p $p -o cmd=)";\
     echo "$l"$p;\
  done
```

Notes:

- Obviously you will not type this each time: put the filter code into a function or script (in which case the trailing `;\` strings are unnecessary).
- Because of buffering when `netstat` writes to a pipe, there is a delay before the filter starts processing lines.
- For the same reason, there is the possibility that the program will terminate or `exec` another between when `netstat` outputs the line and `ps` retrieves the arguments for the PID.
- The program path will not displayed if it was not specified when the program was run, since `ps` shows `arg0` from the program's run string.
- Not all systems have the `line` command: if you replace `while l=($line)` with the more usual `while read -r l`, this will trim leading and trailing spaces; when you need to retain them, you can use `while read -r`, with `$REPLY` replacing `$l` (or `while read -r; do l="$REPLY"; ...` for an exact equivalent, with `$l` unchanged).
- The filter works by reading a line from `netstat`, using `sed` to extract the PID from any *number***/***string* sequence, then using `ps -p` on this PID to find the command parameters.
- In the final `echo "$l"$p`, the `$p` is outside the quotes: this is to delete trailing blanks (also a problem with `wine` programs), but it will have the side-effect of compressing multiple spaces in parameters to a single space.

Comment: `read -r` reads the backslashes. To check use of _port_ you probably only want TCP, probably want LISTEN as well as or instead of ESTABLISHED, and maybe don't need names so `-tanp` or `-tlnp`. Since PID/Prog field is last you could `read -ra a` then use `${a[${#a[@]}-1]}` but I'd rather use awk like `netstat...| awk '{p=$NF} sub(/\/.*/,"",p) {x=$0; "ps -p"p" -ocmd=" |getline; $1=$1; print x,$0}'` where `$1=$1` compresses and trims whitespace; to only trim from end `sub(/ *$/,"")`.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 - Thanks for your thoughtful comment, and particularly for pointing out `read -r`: I'll update my answer. I assumed that other `netstat` options would be used, but I was concentrating on the filter, and used `netstat -p` to check my filter on all the different record formats that are output, which include records where the PID/name sequence is not at end of line. I guess it's a matter of familiarity, but I am more used to using bash expansion or `sed` for the sort of filtering you are doing with `awk`.

Comment: Note that in any recent Bash (4.2.46) you get `-bash: line: command not found` so maybe the note is not enough for general purpose.